# Correct way to pass javascript variables

Tags: javascript, express, mongoose, parameter-passing

I'm having trouble understanding how javascript passes variables. I have the following code running in an express controller

```
const {
      sessionID,
      defenderID,
      challengerID
    } = req.body;

    console.log('sessionID', sessionID);
    console.log('defenderID', defenderID);
    console.log('challengeID', challengerID);
    const newGame = await Game.start({
      session: sessionID,
      defender: defenderID,
      challenger: challengerID
    });
```

which is calling the following definition

```
gameSchema.statics.start = async (session, defender, challenger) => {
  const date = new Date();
  console.log('attempting to start a game');
  console.log('session', session);
  console.log('defender', defender);
  console.log('challenge', challenger);
  const newGame = new Game({
    defender: defender,
    challenger: challenger,
    startTime: date
  });
  newGame.session.push(session);
  return await newGame.save().then((game) => game);
}
```

my output is

```
defenderID johndoe
challengeID somechallenge
attempting to start a game
session {
  session: '620c29582ac275bd67cd3cca',
  defender: 'johndoe',
  challenger: 'somechallenge'
}
defender undefined
challenge undefined
```

i'm not exactly sure where im going wrong here, since i was referencing another bit of code that works fine doing this

Comment: i missed the first line for log statment but its 
```
sessionID 620c29582ac275bd67cd3cca
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are passing down an object as a single argument to the `Game.start` method at the time of calling the function but in your function declaration you are expecting 3 arguments i.e session, defender and challenger. Since `session` is the first argument in your function declaration, you are getting the object in console.log for `session`.

You can fix it by passing all the arguments individually when calling the method like this-

```
  const {
    sessionID,
    defenderID,
    challengerID
  } = req.body;

 console.log('sessionID', sessionID);
 console.log('defenderID', defenderID);
 console.log('challengeID', challengerID);
 
 const newGame = await Game.start(sessionID, defenderID, challengerID);
```

**Another way to fix it** would be to change the function declaration to accept a single argument which is an object and you can destructure the properties like this

```
gameSchema.statics.start = async ({
 session, 
 defender, 
 challenger
}) => {
  const date = new Date();
  console.log('attempting to start a game');
  console.log('session', session);
  console.log('defender', defender);
  console.log('challenge', challenger);
  const newGame = new Game({
    defender: defender,
    challenger: challenger,
    startTime: date
  });
  newGame.session.push(session);
  return await newGame.save();
}
```

And then you can call the method as you are already doing it

```
const newGame = await Game.start({
  session: sessionID,
  defender: defenderID,
  challenger: challengerID
});
```

Also, you don't need to use `.then` after calling `.save()` as you are already using `async await pattern` and calling `await newGame.save()` will return the saved game document.

```
return await newGame.save();
```

Comment: thanks, the first solution works for me however the second doesn't. it still passes it as undefined. are you aware of any documentation that goes in depth on this topic ?

Comment: also when i dont include the then promise, my .save() doesnt return a value

Comment: For the second approach you need to call the Game.start function same as you were calling it earlier. Can you console.log the result returned from the function when you are not using .then?

Comment: Here's an article on Javascript Function parameters which might be helpful https://dmitripavlutin.com/javascript-function-parameters/

Answer (score 0):

Whole object is passed to first argument (named session):

```
{
      session: sessionID,
      defender: defenderID,
      challenger: challengerID
}
```

You can change call to:

```
const newGame = await Game.start(sessionID, defenderID, challengerID);
```

or method definition to:

```
async (obj) => {
...
const newGame = new Game({
    defender: obj.defender,
    challenger: challenger,
    startTime: date
  });
...
```